# How to close the initial window if it has no title bar

Tags: swift, macos, storyboard

(Swift, macOS, storyboards)

How to close the initial window if there is no title bar?

This line of code closes the initial window. But only if it has Title bar. I put it in AppDelegate.swift > func func applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.close()
```

If the window has no title bar and no close button, is there any other option to close the initial window?

(Be aware that we can close with code a window that we have opened before. But with the window that is Initial and has no title it seems that is different)

SOME CLARIFICATIONS

It seems that some people do not understand the question. I try to give more details.

```
//I can open a regular window:
var controller: NSWindowController?
let storyboard:NSStoryboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
controller = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "identifier2") as? NSWindowController
controller?.showWindow(self)

//Later I can close that window
controller?.close()
```

This code to close the window works only for the window that I have opened. Not for the initial window, the window that opens by default. It does not matter if it has the identifier or not.

To close the initial window this line of code works well, but only if the window has a Title bar:

```
//I can close the initial window if it has Title bar. 
//I put this in func applicationDidFinishLaunching:  
NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.close()
```

So, my question is: How to close the initial window, if that window does not have Title bar.

Some definitions:

- Is Initial Controller. You can see that if you select the Storyboard > Window Controller > Attributes
- Title bar. Storyboard > Window > Show Title Bar and Controls > Close. Both options are not selected.

Comment: There is a petition to close because "it needs more focus". It also has a negative point. Can anyone help me understand why? Can anyone make any suggestions to improve the question?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried after reading the tips in the now removed comments.

Comment: Other ideas: 1. Don't use the initial controller and open the window from code. 2. Store a pointer to the window when it is the only window. 3. Use something unique to this window to find it.

Comment: Are you saying that if the window doesn't have a title bar, it cannot be programatically dismissed? That doesn't seem right, and if indeed this is the case, then it looks like a bug in the SDK. But I doubt there is such a bug...

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] so that we better understand the problem?

Answer (score -2):

A bit vague, so I'll try to give a generic pointer:

Since this is the final window of your program, and nothing will be left once it is gone, could you use NSApplication.shared().terminate(self)?

Comment: If I understand your code closes the program. I do not want to close the program. I am asking to close the initial window.